# escaping double quotes in cgi.FieldStorage() with json.loads python

Tags: python, json, encoding, cgi

if I receive a JSON string with different values I want to escape double quotes.
This is not working because if I want to loop over the values of given fields I need to json.loads(string) first, but this already fails because their is a misleading double quote in one of the values.
If I loop over the raw string it escapes double quotes that are set correctly as well and it fails again.
How would I accomplish to just loop over the values?

```
print("Test started...")
try:
    import json
    import cgi
    form3 = cgi.FieldStorage()
    print("cgi Fieldstorage loaded in form3...")

    form2 = form3["json"].value
    print("form 2 is now form3.value...")


    print("loop now starting...")
    for x in form2:
        print("in loop...")

        x = x.replace('"','\"')
        print("dumped an item in form1...")

    form1 = json.loads(form2)
    print("form1 is being prepared with json.loads... ")

    print("dumped form1 string looks like : " + json.dumps(form1))

# handeling JSON-Exceptions thrown by corrupted parameters
except (ValueError, KeyError):
    import sys
    print("Encoding Error")
    sys.exit()
```

Example input from adressbar:

```
http://localhost/script.py?json={"field":"value","field2":"value","field3":"val"ue"}
```

note that value from field 3 should escape as following:

```
http://localhost/script.py?json={"field":"value","field2":"value","field3":"val\"ue"}
```

what happens if the string is escaped without loading it as json via json.loads(string)

```
http://localhost/script.py?json={\"field\":\"value\",\"field2\":\"value\",\"field3\":\"val\"ue\"}
```

it's obvious that this happens, but this string can't be loaded via json.loads anymore
neither can I json.loads and afterwards escape the values because json.loads won't recognize a correct json string (value3 corrupted)

Comment: where does the JSON text come from? What happens if you don't escape double quotes? What do you want to happen instead? Please, provide example input/output.

Comment: thank you for answering! I added some explanations to make things clear.

Comment: *your input is not json* (worse. It looks like it but it is not). How do you know that you need `:` instead of `,` after `field3` or what quote symbol need to be escaped, or that you don't need some other transformation?

Comment: sorry that was a typo, it has to be `:` instead of `,`. the double quote after `val` needs to be escaped (`val"ue` e.g. was an user input)

Comment: how do you know it *programmatically*? Why is there an unescaped quote?

Comment: e.g. if a user types the values in the adress bar directly. There is no way to escape it before script excecution then.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40915/discussion-between-codehai-and-j-f-sebastian)